# How do I compare two CSVs and remove a row if a key matches in ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

Forgive me as I'm pretty new to ruby, but I have two CSVs and I want to compare two CSV files and delete the row from CSV1 if something from CSV2 matches a key in CSV1

CSVs (with lots of redactions) for example:

```rb
# csv1

xyz_id,first_nm,last_nm
100001,Person,one
200002,Person,two
300003,Person,three
400001,Person,four
500001,Person,five
```

```rb
#csv2

id,name,first_name,last_name,address .....
1234,person,wun
1235,person,tuh who
1236,person,tree
100001,Person,one
```

**If** there is something matching in csv2, delete the entire row from CSV1.

### Here is what I've tried:

I saw in another question I could leverage the usage of `delete_if` but I'm slightly confused on the implementation of it. However, this is my code:

```rb
csv1 = CSV.table('./csv/csv1.csv', headers: true)
csv2 = CSV.table('./csv/csv2.csv', headers: true)

csv1.delete_if do |csv1row|
    csv2.each do |csv2row|
        csv1row[:xyz_id] == csv2[:id]
    end
end
```

I'm also not sure if this is working. Do I have to write it back to `csv1`? or create a whole new CSV for this? Is it possible to write it back to csv1 *if* things have been deleted?

Comment: When giving any example a cardinal rule is to show the Ruby object you want returned. CSV files do not have "keys". Do you mean you wish to delete a line in the first file if the value of any field in that line equals the value of the corresponding field of any line in the second file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in the right path. The [`Array#delete_if`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/delete_if) method expects the block to return a boolean. Take this example from the Ruby documentation:

```
scores = [ 97, 42, 75 ]
scores.delete_if {|score| score < 80 }   #=> [97]
```

In your case, you just have to change that `Array#each` call to `Array#any?`. That will delete rows from `csv1` that have a matching ID in `csv2`.

```
csv1.delete_if do |csv1row|
  csv2.any? { |csv2row| csv1row[:xyz_id] == csv2[:id] }
end
```

Comment: Brilliant! I wasn't aware of `.any?` I need to read through rubydocs again . Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

With the below code first it'll load both csv files to the variables i.e. `csv1` and `csv2` with headers. Once file has been loaded we fetched common ids available to both columns `xyz_id` from `csv1` and column `id` from `csv2`. Then deleted recode from `csv1` if `xyz_id` available in the `common_ids` array.

```
csv1 = CSV.table('csv_1.csv', headers: true)
csv2 = CSV.table('csv_2.csv', headers: true)
common_ids = csv1[:xyz_id] & csv2[:id]
csv1.delete_if {|row| common_ids.include?(row[:xyz_id])}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! When you do `common_ids = csv1[:xyz_id] & csv2[:id]`, I figure it will find common IDs, but what does the `&` do in general? and for this use case?

Comment: As we know binary `&` operator it'll return number 1 once the both digits are 1 other wise 0. In our case, number is checking one by one to the another array and return only those numbers which is available to both the array.