# With ruby, how do I format a CSV correctly under it's respective header/column?

Tags: ruby, csv

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69472578/how-do-i-compare-two-csvs-and-remove-a-row-if-a-key-matches-in-ruby), I had a main CSV file and I had two extra CSVs. I wanted to go through both of these CSVs and remove the entries from the main CSV if something matched within these two files. My solution ended up looking like this:

```rb
require 'csv'

main_list = CSV.table('./script/main.csv', headers: true)
already_called = CSV.table('./script/already_called.csv', headers: true)
already_mailed = CSV.table('./script/already_mailed.csv', headers: true)

updated_list = main_list.delete_if do |main_row|
    already_called.any? { |called_row| main_row[:id] == called_row[:id] }
    already_mailed.any? { |mailed| main_row[:curr_addr_line_1] == mailed[:street_address_1] }
end

CSV.open('./script/final_list.csv', 'w', headers: main_list.headers, write_headers: true) do |writer|
    writer << updated_list
end
```

*I believe* this works, and now I want to write to `final_list.csv` with the data matching the headers, but this is not the case.

My ideal format is something along the lines of

```
id,nm,last_nm,first_nm,birth_dt, ......
"10001","PERSON, PersonA","PERSON","PersonA","5/5/1999"......
"10031","PERSON, PersonB","PERSON","PersonB","3/1/1901"......
```

However with my code above, I get something like this:

```
# redacted some headers
# headers seem to be fine?
id,nm,last_nm,first_nm,birth_dt, ......
"1003984,""PERSON, PersonA"",PersonA,PERSON,5/5/1999,58,MALE,ENGLISH,,
XXX-XXX-XXXX,XXX@XXX.COM,PO BOX ???,,CITY,STATE,ANOTHER PLACE,UNITED STATES,
???,""???"",4082000,INSURANCE,2,INSURANCE,""408,200,001.00"",MEDICARE A AND B,
""11,043,785.00"",2500084,ADDRESS,1,COMMERCIAL,
""27,083.00"",ADDRESS,I50.32,SYMPTOMS,???,DATE,OFFICE VISIT,""PERSON"",6/18/2021,""PERSON"",
0,,0,0,,,,""PERSON"",1,55.0,10/7/2020,,,
""[""""???"""",""""???"""",""""???""""]"",""[""""diag""""]"",
""[""""MED"""",""""MED"""",""""MED"""",""""MEDS"""",""""XYZ MED"""",
""""XYZ MEDS"""",""""MEDS"""",""""MEDIS"""",""""XYZ MEDS"""""",,,,,,

............ and more
```

I've redacted a lot of information above but I wanted to show the format I was getting. When I upload this to Google Sheets, it all outputs into one row **with the headers being in the correct place**, at least. However, it seems my entire output is just in one very long row. What's especially confusing are the long quotes at the end.

How do I match up the headers and columns correctly?

I've looked around for a while and I'm unsure how to proceed. Ruby is not my language of choice so I really appreciate some guidance!

Comment: You probably have to push each row in `updated_list` to `writer`, not the whole list at once. (use a loop)

Comment: This actually worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Stephan I ended up with this and it worked!

```rb
CSV.open('./script/final_list.csv', 'w', headers: main_list.headers, write_headers: true) do |writer|
    updated_list.each { |row| writer << row }
end
```